# Importing a huge sql data file into production database

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc, liquibase

We have extracted a lot of data which we would like to import into our production database. My first idea was to create a migration SQL file, just as we would usually do with schema changes, which gets run at the next deployment.

It turned out, however, that the created SQL file is 220MB, so it's not practical to put it under version control.

What would be the best way of doing the import? Should I connect to the prod database from my dev machine and execute the script locally?

Comment: What kind of file did you create?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the file contains an INSERT with 1.5M rows.

Comment: It's probably more efficient to store that data as a plain text ("CSV") file and then use the `loadData` command: http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/load_data.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Assuming I go with this solution, I would need to put the CSV somewhere. Since we're using automatic deployments, I don't access the prod server directly, but instead everything is built/deployed from our repo. So I would need to add the CSV to git.

Comment: Yes, why wouldn't you put that into git?

Comment: As I said, it is 200+MB, would be highly impractical to have such big files in git, and have it deployed to the server every time.

Comment: Shrug, Why would that be "highly impractical".?

Comment: Why not to put it into some artifact repository like Nexus?